# Instagram API Returning Invalid Format for Callback_Url Error

Tags: api, instagram, callbackurl

I'm using the [Instagram API](http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/).

I'm trying a simple post for a subscription request, and I keep getting

> "Invalid format for 'callback_url'. URL must start with http:// or
>   https://".

It clearly starts with that.

I can't find anyone online that's running into this same problem.

Tried the post with a clear callback url:

```
http://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/?client_id={client_id}&client_secret={secret}&object=tag&aspect=media&object_id=skateboarding&callback_url=http://skateparkoftampa.com/spot/instagram_callback.aspx
```

And with an HTML encoded callback `URL`:

```
http://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/?client_id={client_id}&client_secret={secret}&object=tag&aspect=media&object_id=skateboarding&callback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fskateparkoftampa.com%2Fspot%2Finstagram_callback.aspx
```

Also tried it with both GET and POST, also by letting the API console create the request by simply filling in the parameters fields, etc.  I feel like I'm missing something really obvious or something, but I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: Ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @TomHall - Did you have any resolution on this?

Comment: @dt1369 I did get it working in the end. I used the Instagram API Console (https://apigee.com/console/instagram) to keep on trying until it worked. I'm pretty sure one of my problems was that I wasn't returning the correct value when the call was made... Good luck!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid format for callback url - Instagram API and python requests library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552551/invalid-format-for-callback-url-instagram-api-and-python-requests-library)

Answer (score 0):

As sais on [Endpoints page](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/):

> All endpoints are only accessible via **https**

You should use your own `CLIENT-ID` and `SECRET-ID` and `callback url` (so don't use `API console`).

Your `callback url` may be without `https`.

Just use link with `https`:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```

Try examples from [this page](https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/)

You should use `POST` request to subscribe and unsubscribe, and `GET` to get list of subscriptions. Please, read [documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/) accurately.