# Invalid format for callback url - Instagram API and python requests library

Tags: python, post, instagram, python-requests

I have the following code to get the images from urls

```
    params = {'client_id':settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_KEY,
              'client_secret':settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_SECRET,
              'aspect':'media',
              'object_id':instance.hashtag,
              'callback_url':'http://localhost:8000/campaigns/hook'}
    response = requests.post('https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/', 
                             params=params)
```

I am using the requests library for sending the post request. But It returns the error message

> "Invalid format for \"callback_url\". URL must","start with \"http:\/\/\" or \"https:\/\/\""

I have no idea i am receiving this message. I am sending the request the following url .

https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/?client_secret=ZZZZZZZ&callback_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fcampaigns%2Fhook&aspect=media&client_id=YYYYYYYYYYY&object_id=asda'

What is the difference btw  `http%3A%2F%2F and http:\/\/\`

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to GET or to POST to the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `data` parameter to post data:

```
response = requests.post('https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/', 
                         data=params)
```

The `params` keyword is for `GET` parameters only.

You must use a *publicly reachable* callback URL; `http://localhost` is *not* a URL Instagram can reach.

Comment: Now receiving INVALID Response 400. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope; 400 indicates the server things *you* posted incorrect information. Is there an error body? Look at the `response.headers` and `response.content` (there might perhaps even be a `response.json()`) to see if the server gave you any hints about what might be wrong.